# How do I allow pop up/Redirection with Edge Chromium Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

Popup and redirections are blocked be default on browsers that are opened by the Edge Chromium WebDriver. The version of browser I am using is Version 84.0.522.61 (Official build) (64-bit) and the WebDriver is 84.0.522.63

With Chrome adding the ChromeCapablilties helps:

```
            chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
            setDriver(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
```

Is there an equivalent of this with Edge Driver too?

Comment: Do you want to allow [this setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77ztr.png) in Edge Chromium? The new Edge is based on Chromium and you can use Chromium-Specific Options with setting the `UseChromium` property to `true`. You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp#use-chromium-specific-options). Besides, I suggest you to use the same WebDriver version with the Edge version.

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou,

Thanks for your prompt response, it seems this should solve it, but I need the java equivalent of this. Is there any Java related literature for this.

Thanks,
Prakash

Comment: Could you please provide the selenium code for showing the popup? Generally the popups are shown by the sites and we can handle them using selenium. I'm not sure what kind of popup you want to show using WebDriver. You can provide a more complete code sample so that we won't misunderstand the issue.